# Get image from web with URI

Tags: android

What is wrong with this code. It does not give an error but no image can be seen

```
ImageView a= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

String imageBaseDirectory = "www.dha.com.tr/newpics/news/";
String imageName = "230620111356175716857.jpg";
a.setImageURI(Uri.parse(imageBaseDirectory+imageName));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you should add `http://` at the beginning of you URI:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.dha.com.tr/newpics/news/230620111356175716857.jpg");
```

---

`ImageView` does not support loading images from remote locations. Only resources or files on local file system. In your case you should see warning in `LogCat`:

```
06-23 15:19:52.487: WARN/System.err(27097): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/www.dha.com.tr/newpics/news/230620111356175716857.jpg (No such file or directory)
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.openImpl(Native Method)
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(OSFileSystem.java:152)
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:82)
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:134)
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:349)
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:399)
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromPath(Drawable.java:801)
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:516)
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:293)
...
06-23 15:19:52.503: WARN/System.err(27097):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-23 15:19:52.503: INFO/System.out(27097): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: http://www.dha.com.tr/newpics/news/230620111356175716857.jpg
```

---

You should download the image yourself and then specify local path for `setImageURI`.

Answer (score 4):

Try using

```
a.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(imageBaseDirectory+imageName).openConnection().getInputStream()));
```

as suggested in the Android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI%28android.net.Uri%29).

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted here the Logcat output so that we may come to know about the possible problems.

But still you may forget to add INTERNET permission inside the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uri.parse needs an encoded URI string so I think you have to add the scheme.

```
String imageBaseDirectory = "http://www.dha.com.tr/newpics/news/";
```